# How to format splunk graphs to show multiple lines (one line for each method)?

Tags: splunk, splunk-formula

I am new to splunk reports, I am trying to achieve the following:
I want to generate splunk logs report (graphical) for API performances with execution time on x-axis and method names on y-axis. I am trying to run following query:

```
cs_dataowner_id="ICTO-31263" cs_stage =  UAT 
| search cs_component_id="icomply-gpat-api-buslogs" 
| search Action=API_PERFORMANCE 
| table Message Execution_Time 
| sort by Execution_Time desc
```

Expected line graph should show a single line for each method (API) expanding with time on x axis hence number of lines on y-axis should be equal to number of apis/methods called in that time range.

Current output: A single line on y axis for all the methods (here I have 2 apis).

I tried all the formatting options but nothing worked.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of piped `search` commands, do it all on the first line:

```
cs_dataowner_id="ICTO-31263" cs_stage=UAT cs_component_id="icomply-gpat-api-buslogs" Action=API_PERFORMANCE
```

Instead of the `sort` and `table` commands, use `chart`:

```
| chart count(Message) as Messages over Execution_Time by Message
```

This command graphs the number of calls to each API with Execution_Time on the X-axis and separate lines for each API (Message).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I was looking for, though here I see now the messages are expanding over time indefinitely, meaning I want to give a time gap on x axis to distribute the messages evenly with time for example with range of 10 seconds or 20 seconds. Is there any command like group by ?

Comment: Insert a `bin` command to group events by time.  For example, `| bin span=20s _time`.

Comment: I want to improvise my graph with following requirement: 
 Exactly what I am looking for is line graph of methods (Apis) that will be distributed over time (on x-axis) and will expand based on  Execution_Time. You can think of a timechart which takes time on x-axis by default and other parameter on y axis but doesn't allow to take more than one parameter (for example here I want one more paramter, method). Can you suggest a query for this ?